# How to Animate two image view from Center to opposite to each other?

Tags: android, animation

i want to animate the two images from middle of the screen to opposite to each other. like below image.

[image]

whatever i have done so far is right now i am able animate only one image from left to right and vice versa but now i want to animate them from middle.

here is my code :

```
b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        width = display.getWidth();
        final Animation posX = new TranslateAnimation(0, width - 50, 0, 0);
        posX.setDuration(1500);
        posX.setFillAfter(true);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                logo.startAnimation(posX);
                logo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

**Edit:**

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/set_user_profile_back"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
            android:src="@drawable/prev_btn" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
            android:src="@drawable/next_btn" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks

Comment: You have to use object animator, it can animate more than one item at same time.

Comment: give each image an animation listener each with specific translate values

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper it would be great if you can provide any related link

Comment: @FahadIshaque thanks for suggestion, can you provide any example ?

Comment: I think this link can help you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196209/simultaneous-translations-on-android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    ImageView img1 = findViewById(R.id.img1);
    ImageView img2 = findViewById(R.id.img2);

        Animation img1_Anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                R.anim.img1_animation);
        img1_Anim.setAnimationListener(AnimationListener);
        img1.startAnimation(img1_Anim);

Animation img2_Anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                R.anim.img2_animation);
        img2_Anim.setAnimationListener(AnimationListener);
        img2.startAnimation(img2_Anim);

    private AnimationListener AnimationListener = new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {


            }
        };
```

**img1_animation**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true" >

    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="50%"
        android:toXDelta="0%" />



</set>
```

**img2_animation**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true" >

    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="50%"
        android:toXDelta="100%" />



</set>
```

Comment: Thanks for code, image are animating but from up to down and vice versa,i want to animate left to right and vice versa

Comment: Oh I am sorry , you have to make translate in x axis not y

Comment: Thaks its working fine but animating in very few area, may be there is problem with setting those two imageviews any suggestion? i have edited the question and added the xml and how do i set both image views at center of the button before starting animation ?

Comment: what do you mean by animating in very few area ?

Comment: i mean it should move till end of background image

Comment: You can get the width of the image view and devide it by two , and set the value of fromXDelta and toXdelta

Comment: Right to left animation is not working properly, i tried to set this parameters  `android:fromXDelta="375%"`  `android:toXDelta="0%"` but its not moving from last to first while left to right is working fine any idea why its not working?